# How to get the length of data inside the cells with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find a way to get the elements of the cell as a string and then use this length as a integer if I write something like  `len(range(cell(i,j))` then it gets stuck in a error of syntax. I tried to find something here in stack. I know that I would need to convert this range to a string, but I don't know how to do it.

Sorry, I'm new to VB

Comment: try `len(cell(i,j))`.

Comment: the problem is the `range(cell(i,j))` part not the Len.  Remove the `Range()` Just use: `len(cell(i,j))`

Comment: It doesnt works either. A compilation error appears.

Comment: Sorry, was distracted by your `Range` (and Scott Craner also). It must be `Cells`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Len(Cells(i,j))` but `Cells(i,j).Characters.Count` will also work.

BigBen pointed out in the comments that `Range().Characters.Count` throws a error when working with numeric data.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen.   I didn't think to test for it.